# Firebase: sendPasswordResetEmail - config_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am working on a project that uses Firebase for authentication, and I've encountered an issue when trying to send a password reset email. The error message I'm receiving is:

> *config_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function

// ../config/firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    // Your Firebase config here
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export { auth };
```

// My authentication file

```
import { auth } from '../config/firebase';

export const recoverPassword = async (email) => {
    const recoveryResponse = {
        loading: false,
        success: false,
        error: null,
        data: null,
    };

    try {
        recoveryResponse.loading = true;
        await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
        recoveryResponse.success = true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending password reset email:', error.message);
        recoveryResponse.error = `Error sending password reset email: ${error.message}`;
    } finally {
        recoveryResponse.loading = false;
    }

    return recoveryResponse;
};
```

I have checked that the auth object is properly initialized, and it does have other authentication methods available. However, the sendPasswordResetEmail method seems to be missing.

I'm using Firebase version 10.7.2. Is there something I'm missing or is there a compatibility issue? Any help would be appreciated!